# Why doesn't Java calculate this calculation right?

Tags: java, math, operators

I have recently started learning Java. I started working on a simple mathematical project for approximating Euler number with (1 + 1 / x)^x. But at the very first step, the program returned the wrong value. Here is my minimised code, where the solution is wrong.

```java
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(1 + 1 / 2);
    }
}
```

The program returns 1. The result seems to me pretty contradictory. How can 1 + 1 / 2 return 1? I was expecting 1.5.

I tried some debugging:

```java
double x = 1 + Math.pow(2, -1);
System.out.println(x);
```

And now it is working. How come that?

Comment: how about `double x = 1.0 + 1 / 2.0;`? see..  the type inferred!

Comment: Why do you say it's wrong, given that `1/2 == 0`?

Comment: 1/2 uses integer math and results in zero since integer math rounds down to the nearest integer. The right-hand side uses all integer math, then assigns the result to a double (x).

Comment: Oh, I should write "System.out.println(1.+1./2.)"! Thank you!

Comment: for something like `1/2` you can do any of these `1/2.`  or `1./2` or `(double)1/2`,  or `1/(double)2`

Comment: Or `0.5` if you're in a hurry.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Actually I was making a code, which produces the solution for the every *i* from 0 to 100000 that makes the solution to (1+1/i)^i. (Euler number approximation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a division on the two integers. I should make this on two doubles or floats:

```java
System.out.println(1.0 + 1.0 / 2.0);
```

And since we can shorten the doubles 1.0 -> 1., we could shorten this:

```java
System.out.println(1.+1./2.);
```

Thank you for your answer! (Especially [Naman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746118/naman), [njzk2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671543/njzk2) and [FredK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4971422/fredk) in the comments.)